# AWS Step Functions: How to set a condition in choice state, if date is less that current date minus 24 hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine which has a choice state. In that choice state I want one of the conditions to be if a certain date is less that the current date minus 24 hours.

How can I achieve this? Must I use a lambda function?

My date is in ISO 8601 format like `2023‐08‐21T15:41:42Z`

Comment: What format is the date in?  Please add some code details to the question.

Comment: It is in ISO 8601 format. Like 2023‐08‐21T15:41:42Z.

Comment: @fedonev I have updated the question as per your request.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no support from [AWS States Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html) to work with dates.

Is passing the limits as part of the body an option for you? If so, there may be a couple of choices -

1. Work with dates as a complex object with day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, and time zone attributes i.e.,

```
{
    "day": 21,
    "month": 8,
    "year": 2023,
    "hour": 21,
    "minute": 43,
    "second": 32,
    "millis": 345,
    "zone": 0
}
```

2. Work with dates in their number format. Dates are basically the number of seconds passed since epoch. For the timestamp defined in (1), the same will be about `1692654212.345` seconds.

Following one of the approaches mentioned above should let you use the state machine language when defining the conditions for a choice state.